# How to Encrypt Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

We can precompile our (ASP.NET) websites and can publish only the IL code, so that the source code is not available to the customer.

But how do we do it for stored procedures written in SQL Server.  I mean, when we give the customer the DB, he could see all my stored procedures and can modify the same... How could I protect it.

Thanks

Raja

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "give the vendor"?  Is this an ISP, or a support request where the vendor needs to build your environment?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.. I really meant customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old problem. Here are a few answers I've picked up here and there:

- Encrypt the stored procedures. As has
  already been pointed out twice, this
  doesn't really work, as 5 minutes of
  Googling will find several hacks.
- Write the stored procedures as CLR
  procedures. Harder to hack than
  "regular" stored procedures, probably
  a lot more effort to produce and
  support.
- Submit all queries dynamically from
  your compiled IL code. I understand
  it can be done reasonably secure from
  SQL injection attack, but make darn
  sure before you release. (Maybe use Linq to do this?)
- Convert all database object names
  (tables, columns, procedures) to
  guids or random gibberish. They could
  read it, but that wouldn't help much.
- I am not totally conversant on encryption within SQL 2005 and up. I really don't *think* you can use it on code-based objects (procedures, functions, etc.), but maybe you can?

But by and large, once you give a copy of your database to someone with SysAdmin rights, they can do pretty much anything they want with it.

Comment: +1, can't be done if anyone has sysadmin or physical access. Your dynamic query point: profiler will show you what's going on there...

Comment: Once upon a time, didn't Profiler "blank out" any submitted query that contained the word "password"? Alas, looks like 2005+ doesn't do that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

use WITH ENCRYPTION

example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prTest
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Keep in mind that it can be cracked and also make sure you have the unencrypted source code backed up

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ... WITH ENCRYPTION
```

However note that this encryption is really more like obfuscation, and there are several ways to bypass it if your vendor is determined, including the DAC connection, some 3rd party products (including RedGate SQL Prompt), and code samples you can readily find online.